# Survey question is independent of the way it is asked.

Tags: probability, independence

[image]

I know that I need to use the independent events formula $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$ somehow.
But I can't figure out which events to use for $A$ and $B$.

I think that the total number of people surveyed is 91 (sum of all rows).
I don't understand how I can find the probability of each event though. For example, the probability of "being suprised" $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Lets manually compute $P(A)$, $P(S)$ and $P(A \cap S)$.

The probability of the question being asked in form A is
$P(A) = \frac{50}{91}$

The probability of a student being surprised is
$P(S) = \frac{11}{91}$

The joint probability of a question being asked in form A and a student being surprised (i.e. the probability of a student being surprised by a question in form A) is
$P(A \cap S) = P(A, S) = \frac{6}{91}$

You can manually compute these to find that $P(A)P(S) = \frac{50\cdot11}{91^2} \approx 0.066 \approx \frac{6}{91} = P(A \cap S)$.

Its up to you to decide if this is sufficiently close to equality between $P(A)P(S)$ and $P(A \cap S)$ - which would indicate that $A$ and $S$ are independent.